# My SQL is only bringing results if there are comments

Tags: sql, innodb

I have an SQL query that pulls all of my blogs out, with the blog author and it does this for every blog comment corresponding to the comment author.

These 3 tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `blogs` (
  `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `blogs`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
    ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `blogs`
    MODIFY `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

ALTER TABLE `blogs`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `blogs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` 
    (`uuid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


CREATE TABLE `blogs_comments` (
  `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `blog_uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `blogs_comments`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
    ADD KEY `user_uuid` (`user_uuid`),
    ADD KEY `blog_uuid` (`blog_uuid`);

ALTER TABLE `blogs_comments`
    MODIFY `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

ALTER TABLE `blogs_comments`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `blogs_comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`blog_uuid`) 
    REFERENCES `blogs` (`uuid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    ADD CONSTRAINT `blogs_comments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_uuid`) 
    REFERENCES `users` (`uuid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `foreName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `surName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `users`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
    MODIFY `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    b.uuid AS 'Blog ID', b.title AS 'Blog Title',
    b.detail AS 'Blog Body', u.uuid AS 'Blog Author ID',
    u.username AS 'Blog Author Username',
    (SELECT bc.comment WHERE u.uuid = bc.user_uuid) AS 'Comment',
    (SELECT u.uuid WHERE u.uuid = bc.user_uuid) AS 'Comment Author ID',
    (SELECT u.username WHERE u.uuid = bc.user_uuid) AS 'Comment Author Username'
FROM
    blogs b
INNER JOIN
    blogs_comments bc
ON
    b.uuid = bc.blog_uuid
INNER JOIN
    users u
ON
    b.user_id = u.uuid
```

This query works fine if there are comments on the blogs. If there is no comments, the blog is not returning. Does anyone have any idea on how I could change this around so it brings out blogs even if there is no comments?

Thanks in advance

Update: My PDO looks like this:

```
$stmt = (new PDO('dsn', 'user', 'pswd'))->Prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([], PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_export($stmt->fetchAll()); // Array holds nothing for blogs with no comments
```

Comment: No indexes?  At least have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  UUIDs will limit scalability.  See also tips [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: Every `uuid` is a primary key with auto_increment @RickJames for some reason, my SQL dump didn't add that. I also have foreign keys set up

Comment: I'm getting more confused.  I see no `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  UUID and auto_increment are two different animals.  Perhaps shortly after the `CREATE TABLE` is an `ALTER TABLE .. ADD PRIMARY KEY ..`?

Comment: @RickJames Just checked, there is. Sorry about not providing that part, I simply just copied the `create table` part from the SQL export assuming that would cover everything.

Comment: Ooookkkk, I would like to see the keys.

Comment: @RickJames updating the question now :)

Comment: Updated @RickJames I recently changed the foreign key ON DELETE to cascade tho I think

Comment: The `(255)` on `INT` is meaningless; an `INT` is always a 32-bit number.  The convention is `id` for a `PRIMARY KEY` and (often) `AUTO_INCREMENT`; `uuid` for funny strings like `3a52a7c6-e066-11e8-bcc6-80fa5b366bce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `left join`, starting with `users`.  However, I think your real confusion is that you need to join to `users` twice:

```
SELECT b.uuid AS Blog_ID,
       b.title AS Blog_Title,
       b.detail AS Blog_Body,
       u.uuid AS Blog_Author_ID,
       u.username AS Blog_Author_Username,
       bc.comment AS Comment,
       bc.user_uuid AS Comment_Author_ID,
       ubc.username AS Comment_Author_Username
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     blogs b
     ON b.user_id = u.uuid LEFT JOIN
     blogs_comments bc
     ON b.uuid = bc.blog_uuid LEFT JOIN
     users ubc
     ON bc.user_uuid = u.uuid;
```

Notes:

- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- Do not give your column aliases names that need to be escaped.  I replaced the spaces with underscores.
- If you want both the name of the blog user and the comment user, then you need to join to `users` twice.
- I don't understand why you were using subqueries in the `SELECT` with no `FROM` clause.

Comment: That is brilliant! I really appreciate the notes, everything I know is self taught so that's probably why I monged it and put subqueries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    blogs_comments bc
```

should do it.